# Issues with Python parsing dictionary output of Amazon RDS instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to parse what I guess is a dict output from AWS's boto interface in Python, which should give me information about all of my Amazon RDS (database) instances. I am new to all of the tools I am using here, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to treat it like an array, which may be a bad premise to start with, since it's a dict type. The below code works fine to pull two (2) instances, which is what is strange - it's at least repeatable once, and I've verified by printing the dict output shows all four (4) instances I have running in the Region - but it does not pull the latter two in the output. When I use len() to measure the length of the output, it returns 2.

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to this code to make it actually parse out all of the instances returned? (And then the functionality is to look for a rebootAllowed tag, which if 1, stops the instance... this appears to work fine, but again, only for the first two results returned.)

```
import json
import boto3

region = 'us-east-1'
rds = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Ingest all RDS instances
    dbinstances = rds.describe_db_instances() # Filtering by instance status is not supported
    
    print('* * *')
    
    # Set db instance counter for below loop   
    dbi = 0

    # Loop through each running RDS instance, checking tags and shutting down if tags match
    for dbinstance in dbinstances:
        # Set default values for tags we'll parse
        rebootAllowed = 0
        # We'll need this later
        try:
            dbinstanceId = dbinstances.get('DBInstances')[dbi]['DBInstanceIdentifier']
            dbinstanceArn = dbinstances.get('DBInstances')[dbi]['DBInstanceArn']
            rdstags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=dbinstanceArn)
            # Attempt to look into tags for EC2s that have them. If they don't, we'll get an exception
            try:
                # Does the instance have the rebootAllowed tag? Great, what's its value?
                if 'rebootAllowed' in rdstags['TagList'][dbi]['Key']:
                    rebootAllowed = rdstags['TagList'][dbi]['Value']
                # Let's log what we're doing.
                print('Examining RDS instance ' + dbinstanceId + '...')
                # Attempt to stop instance
                try:
                    if rebootAllowed == '1':
                        message = '-- This instance CAN be stopped. Doing that now.'
                        rdsid = [dbinstanceId]
                        rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=dbinstanceId)
                    elif rebootAllowed == '0':
                        message = '-- This instance is BLOCKED from being stopped. Doing nothing.'
                    else:
                        message = '-- This instance does not have the tags used by this script. Skipping.'
                except Exception, err:
                    message = 'Error with RDS instance: instanceId: ' +  err
                    raise err
                print (message)
                print ('* * *')
                dbi += 1
            except:
                print('Examining RDS instance ' + dbinstanceId + ')')
                print('-- An EXECPTION occurred while analyzing this instance. This could be because the instance has no tags at all.')
                print('* * *')
                dbi += 1
        except:
            print('End of list. Script complete.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tough to tell exactly what's going on, especially since we don't exactly know what the shape of the dict you're trying to iterate is, but it does seem like you have a sense of the underlying problem: you're not really handling this iteration very pythonically.

I went and looked up the output, and found this sample:

```
{
    "DBInstances": [
        {
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "mydbinstancecf",
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t3.small",
            "Engine": "mysql",
            "DBInstanceStatus": "available",
            "MasterUsername": "masterawsuser",
            "Endpoint": {
                "Address": "mydbinstancecf.abcexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
                "Port": 3306,
                "HostedZoneId": "Z2R2ITUGPM61AM"
            },
            ...some output truncated...
        }
    ]
}
```

So right off the bat, you can simplify your loop by cutting out the extraneous data in `dbinstances`

```py
# dbinstances = rds.describe_db_instances() becomes
dbinstances = rds.describe_db_instances()["DBInstances"]
```

now, you're dealing with an array of db instances. In a python for loop, you get each element of the iterarable (list) as the variable. There's no need, in this case, to maintain that `dbi` counter at all. If you *do* want to be counting the elements, you can do this `for i, e in enumerate(my_list):` where `i` is the index, and `e` is the element.

so your loop becomes more like this:

```py
for instance in dbinstances: 
# Set default values for tags we'll parse
    rebootAllowed = 0
    # We'll need this later
    try:
       dbinstanceId = instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
       dbinstanceArn = instance['DBInstanceArn']
       rdstags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=dbinstanceArn)
#     ... the rest is left as an exercise for Josh
```

As a general suggestion, when designing this kind of algorithm in Python, make heavy use of the REPL. You can poke around and try things out to quickly get a sense of the actual structure of the data.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, and I will give this a whirl; the reason I had the dbi counter was because I would get errors if I wasn't specifying an index, but if narrowing the scope of the original request will help make the iterations more obvious to the loop, perhaps it won't be necessary.

Comment: if you don't select the array within the original return value, your loop only ever has the one element, which is the list of instances itself, though you wanted to be iterating over each element in that list.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, with one more note (that wasn't part of my original inquiry): list_tags_for_resource(arn) needs its own for loop if you have more than one tag on a resource. This worked. Thanks!